# The classifying space of open covers of a manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, manifolds, classifying-spaces

Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $d$ and let $\mathsf{Disk}_{/M}$ be the category of open subsets of $M$ that are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d$ with morphisms given by inclusions.  Let $\mathrm{B} \mathsf{Disk}_{/M}$ be the classifying space of this category.  How do I prove that $\mathrm{B} \mathsf{Disk}_{/M}$ is homotopy equivalent to $M$?  Intuitively, $\mathrm{B} \mathsf{Disk}_{/M}$ should be some thickening of $M$.

I think this might follow from Quillen's theorem A.  In order to apply it, I would first need to exhibit $M$ as the classifying space of some more tractable category.  I thought about $M \simeq \left\lvert \operatorname{Sing} M \right\rvert$, but $\operatorname{Sing} M$ is not the nerve of a category.  The second barycentric subdivision of $\operatorname{Sing} M$ is a category, but it is pretty complicated.

Alternatively, we might try a direct argument.  If I'm not mistaken, we have $$\mathrm{B} \mathsf{Disk}_{/M} \simeq \operatorname*{colim}_{[n] \to \mathsf{Disk}_{/M}} \Delta^n.$$ On the other hand, $$M \cong \operatorname*{colim}_{\mathsf{Disk}_{/M}} \mathbb{R}^d \simeq \operatorname*{hocolim}_{[0] \to \mathsf{Disk}_{/M}} \Delta^0.$$  So one could try to prove that the index categories $\mathsf{Disk}_{/M}^{\mathbf{\Delta}}$ and $\mathsf{Disk}_{/M} \cong \mathsf{Disk}_{/M}^{[0]}$ are sufficiently similar.  I don't quite know what this means precisely, though.

I'll also be happy if someone could provide a reference for the proof - it certainly ought to be well-known.

---

Edit: Writing $M \simeq \operatorname*{hocolim}_{[0] \to \mathsf{Disk}_{/M}} \Delta^0$ is a little duplicitous.  In the first colimit for $\mathrm{B}\mathsf{Disk}_{/M}$, the gluing data is specified by the simplicial identities in $\mathbf{\Delta}$, but in the second homotopy colimit, the gluing data is not visible at all in the expression - it depends on how all the various $\mathbb{R}^d$'s intersect - and is obscured by writing $\mathbb{R}^d \simeq \Delta^0$, which superficially cannot intersect meaningfully.  In other words, this makes the (possible) comparison less obvious.

Comment: I feel like one can do this if they just sink their teeth into it, the same way you do with $|\text{Sing }M|$. The trouble I'm having is that I have no idea how to construct a map in either direction from $M$ or to your classifying space!

Comment: @MikeMiller: There are maps between the index categories $\mathsf{Disk}_{/M}$ and $\mathsf{Disk}_{/M}^{\mathbf{\Delta}}$ given by inclusion as the constant diagram in one direction and evaluation at a vertex in the other.  So this ought to give maps in both directions.  Granted, this is not very explicit at all, but one of the compositions is the identity, which is certainly promising.

Comment: I'm sure there is a much simpler proof, but you do get *a* proof by combining Lemma 5.4.5.10 and Remark 5.4.5.2 from Lurie's *Higher Algebra*.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have at least a sketch of an argument.  Recall, every manifold admits a locally finite *good* open cover $\mathcal{U}$.  Let us write $\mathcal{U}$ also for the poset category of nonempty finite intersections generated by elements of $\mathcal{U}$ ordered by inclusion.  The *nerve theorem* in this case should apply and we deduce that $\mathrm{B}\mathcal{U} \simeq M$.

There is an inclusion of categories $\mathcal{U} \hookrightarrow \mathsf{Disk}_{/M}$.  We want to apply *Quillen's theorem A* to this to show $\mathrm{B}\mathcal{U} \to \mathrm{B}\mathsf{Disk}_{/M}$ is a homotopy equivalence, and then we would be done.  To apply the theorem, we need to check that for each $\mathbb{R}^d$ in $\mathsf{Disk}_{/M}$, the comma category $\mathcal{U}_{\mathbb{R}^d/} := \mathcal{U} \times_{\mathsf{Disk}_{/M}} \mathsf{Disk}_{\mathbb{R}^d/ /M}$ is empty or contractible.  But $\mathcal{U}_{\mathbb{R}^d/}$ has an initial object, namely the intersection of all open sets in the cover containing $\mathbb{R}^d$, hence it is contractible if not empty.  This completes the argument.

Comment: To use Quillen's Theorem A you need the comma categories to be contractible, not empty or contractible. If empties were allowed, you could use Quillen's Theorem A to prove that the classifying space of any category is equivalent to that of the empty category!

Comment: @OmarAntolin-Camarena Thanks!  I was hoping that empty things were vacuously contractible, but you're right that it's not the case.  I don't see a quick fix to my argument, since it's definitely possible for a disk to not be contained in any open set in my chosen good cover.  I don't think it's possible to refine my good cover to a basic locally finite good cover.  Perhaps I can put a metric on the manifold (assume now compact) and consider the subcategory $\mathsf{Disk}^{<\epsilon}_{/M}$ of balls of radius $< \epsilon$ and apply the Lebesgue covering lemma?